# stuck at default page of WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

hello and hope you guys have a fantastic time

I have a problem with my WordPress website, it does now show fallowing elements: my theme, my homepage, my WordPress bar at the top

it just show a empty black blank page with big logo of my website

you can see other part of the website by searching it manually (like: yourname.com/blog)

but not the main home page (like: yourname.com)

please assist me

thanks ❤

Answer (score 2):

Seems most likely a `HTTP 403` or `.htaccess` error or maybe `Permission error`.

Paste this content into .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

In case you cannot find .htaccess file, DOT files are hidden by default. If you are using cPanel, Go to File Manager, click on settings and select show DOT files.

If you still have problems, Go to Chrome Developer Tools(F12 or inspect element) and then to console. Click a screenshot of (red) errors and send it here.

Generally, the second problem might be the Permissions. Do the following in terminal/ssh:

```
chmod 755 /path/to/wordpress/* -r
```

This is a insecure setting as you should keep PHP files on 0644 and other static files on 0755. If it works after this, problem was your permissions.

If you still experience problems, share the Error Log or PHP version and other details.

Comment: 0there are multiple files of htaccess which one should i use?

Comment: also i found this error on console tab from chrome page :

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Multiple ```.htaccess``` file? Delete all of them(Or maybe rename them to .htaccess.bak which would be better option) and create a new .htaccess file and use the content given above and then let me know. Secondly ```Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ``` references to jQuery/Javascript which should not create a problem in this case. This might refer to theme problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

To display your home page at yourname.com you have to change the setting for that.
In your WordPress dashboard go to settings-> reading
[image]

IN static page select the home page which you have to display in yourname.com

Comment: already did this not working